# How to do an "AllNotSatisfy" condition in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

Consider this code:

```
var ints = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
{
   new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "1", "bill" }, { "2", "john" } },
   new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "2", "jane" }, { "3", "alex" } }
};
```

This works:

```
ints.Should().AllSatisfy(x => x.ContainsKey("2"));
```

However, I want to write an assertions that asserts that none of the dictionaries contains a "4" as key...

Initially I thought I could do this:

```
ints.Should().AllSatisfy(x => !x.ContainsKey("2"));
```

But that doesn't work... I get `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await expression, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Is there any way to do this idiomatically in FluentAssertions?

I know that I can do:

```
ints.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("2")).Should().BeEmpty();
```

I'm a little stumped as to why fluent assertions can use actions as conditions like this where the return type is ignored.

Comment: I presume you can do `ints.Should().NotContain(x => x.ContainsKey("2"));`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
ints.Should().OnlyContain(x => !x.ContainsKey("2"));
```